# Can you export an Entity Framework 6 model into a database project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, database, entity-framework

I am designing my DAL by using EF6 and the model first workflow.

It looks like the only way to generate the DB from the models is to connect to an actual DB or DB file and export the models.

I'd like to rather export the DB into a Database project.

Ultimately my solution will have (or more projects).

```
1. A database project representing the underlying database
2. The DAL project which outputs a class library
3. The web project that contains my MVC 5 app
```

Is the only way to do this to have a staging DB and generate the DB from the EF model and then reverse engineer the DB into the DB project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you cannot create "Database project" from EF model (BTW the "Database project" supports only MS SQL, but EF supports any database). Path via staging database is probably easiest.

BTW did you checked [Entity Framework Migrations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591621.aspx)? Might be a way for you and you'll avoid using the "Database project", which is kind of rusty.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I suspected this was the case. Why do you say that the database project is "rusty"? I like it because it allows multiple developers to collaborate on a solution and update the underlying DB if required and check these changes in source control. It is then easy to have a lot more control over deployment. Maybe I need to get more familiar with code first but I am always sceptical of something that is "generating" my DB schema for me.

Comment: Well, for instance it's hard to script it. The "Migrations" are better, i.e. it's not tightly coupled to VS. You can always change how the resulting script will look like. The model is kind of a backbone for the infrastructure to help you generate basics (like column names).